# Why is true that: If $A \succ 0$, $ A \succ B $ $\iff$ $ I -A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2} \succ 0$ ??

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, positive-definite

Why is this true??

If $A \succ 0$, $ A \succ B $ $\iff$ $ I -A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2} \succ 0$

obs: I don't know for sure if one other hypothesis, $B \succeq 0$ ,is necessary here.

In the book, this claim is presented as follows:

[image]

Another question, I may present this in another topic if someone complains, where the hypothesis "$B \succeq 0$" was used in the proof above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author is using the fact that a positive definite matrix has a "square
root" (i.e., $A^{1/2}$ is well-defined and invertible). Then,
$$
A>B\iff A-B>0\iff\underbrace{A^{-1/2}AA^{-1/2}}_{I}-A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2}>0.
$$

Comment: so, the author is multplying the inequality by $A^{-1/2}$ from both sizes? Ok, got this. And, the other part of the question, do you know where the hypothesis "B is +ve semidefinite" was used? Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't see them using that anywhere either.